# Remote validation with additional fields to show errors only in validation summary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, remote-validation

How do I show up only the Remote validation errors in the validation summary and focus all the corresponding textboxes in red color.

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Remote("IsNameExists", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "LastName", ErrorMessage = "Name exists already")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Remote("IsNameExists", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "FirstName", ErrorMessage = "Name exists already")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

From the above code, the remote validation occurs and displays the error message next the property that's been entered at the end.

So, my requirement is to display only the remote validation errors in validation summary.

However, individual property errors (for e.g. "FirstName is required" etc.) should be displayed next to the corresponding properties.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Please review your last paragraph (makes no sense - some punctuation would help). And what is your view? Do you have `@ValidationMessageFor()` associated with the properties?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I did few modifications to my question. Yes, I have @ValidationMessageFor() attribute for individual properties as well.

Comment: That's not possible unless you make some your own major changes to the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive file`. If you really do want this, I suggest removing the `RemoteAttribute` and performing you own client side validation for the `IsNameExists`